# How JdbcTemplate is able to retrive data even table is deleted from Database

Tags: java, spring-boot

Java rest API(Using JDBC template) is working even table is deleted from database(SQL). 
When i restarted server then it's stopped working as Table is not there.
Can some one please explain how it is possible that after table got deleted all API was still working before I restarted Server.